# Three.JS Model exported from editor, bump map not rendering

Tags: three.js

I have a model with a bump map.  It displays great in the three.js [editor](http://threejs.org/editor), but when I export the scene and load it into a scene, the model displays without the bump map. It's puzzling because the envMap and specularMap are loading just fine, but no bump map.  Any ideas?

The exported json is here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/xj8plnceoce1gwh/AABWChVTw6TW2hPXr5a3t9Tpa/Backpack_3_scene.json?dl=0

Here is my code for loading the exported json:

```
// scene

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  // model

  var onProgress = function ( xhr ) {
    if ( xhr.lengthComputable ) {
      var percentComplete = xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100;
      console.log( Math.round(percentComplete, 2) + '% downloaded' );
    }
  };

  var onError = function ( xhr ) {

  };

  var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();

  loader.load(model_json, function(json_scene) {
    scene.add(json_scene);
    render();
  }, onProgress, onError);
```

Comment: From what I see, the bumpScale is set to something very small. Try setting it closer to 1.0 to see if it still does not work.

Comment: @gaitat You led me to the solution -- We have a provided an interface for our client to scale up the models, but this does not adjust the bumpScale proportionally.  Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your json model file the `bumpScale` is set to 0.04. THat is very small to have any effect. You probably need to scale it up.